# Delete Status bar Icon downloaded from web

Tags: security, malware

I joined way2sms to send free SMS from my laptop. Now I find an app icon downloaded to my status bar in my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile. Also, I get debited for calls not made. I am losing money in this scam due to this app downloaded and it does not show up in my running apps menu. I need to find and delete this app.

Answer (score 1):

The app should at least be found in *Settings → Apps → Manage Apps*, where you should be able to uninstall it. Alternatively you can visit the [Playstore website](https://play.google.com/store), log in with your credentials, go to "My Android Apps", select your device (in case you've got more than one in there), find the app in that list, and remove it by hitting the trashcan-symbol.

If all this fails (the second alternative should not, but who knows), your "last resort" will be a factory-reset of your phone (which will remove all data and all apps you've installed).